# Using nextuntil to disable and enable select form elements

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to activate a set of select dropdowns when a radio button is selected, and deactivate when another is selected.

**jQuery:**

```
$(':radio[name!="hours"]').change(function() {
  if ($(this).filter(':checked').val() == "open") {
    $(this).nextUntil("input","select").attr("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $(this).nextUntil("input","select").attr("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form id="providerForm">
  <p><input type="radio" name="hours" value="no" checked="true"> There are no hours at this location</p>
  <p><input type="radio" name="hours" value="yes"> Enter the hours below</p>
  <span id="hoursList">
    <p><label for="monday">Monday: </label><span class="radios"><input type="radio" name="monday" value="closed"/> Closed</span>
    <span class="radios"><input type="radio" name="monday" value="open"/> Open <select name="monStart" id="monStart" disabled></select> to <select name="monEnd" id="monEnd" disabled></select></span></p>
    <p><label for="tuesday">Tuesday: </label><span class="radios"><input type="radio" name="tuesday" id="tueClosed" value="closed"/> Closed</span>
    <span class="radios"><input type="radio" name="tuesday" value="open"/> Open <select name="tueStart" id="tueStart" disabled></select> to <select name="tueEnd" id="tueEnd" disabled></select></span></p>
  </span>
  <input type="submit" id="loginButton" name="submit" value="Add Hours" />
</form>
```

Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/BN6JD/

The select boxes are enabled upon clicking "open" - which is great. However, they do not disable again upon clicking "Closed". Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filtering a single radio input(which is `checked`) not a radio group and `nextUntill` only selects the next siblings of the selected element that doesn't work with your current markup. Also for modifying properties `prop` method should be used instead of the `attr`. Try this:

```
$('input[type=radio][name!="hours"]').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('p') // select the closest parent `p` element
           .find('select') // find `select` elements
           .prop("disabled", this.value === 'closed'); // disable/enable the selects  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6ELcA/

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Is there a reason you changed $(':radio[name!="hours"]') to $('input[type=radio][name!="hours"]') since they both do the same thing?

Comment: @CMH You are welcome, `input[type=radio]` is faster than `:radio` selector. I just prefer to use `tag[attribute]` selectors, there is no specific reason.